# Update layout of Research Assistant badge page

Tags: feature-request, design

The [Tag Editor badge page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/73/tag-editor) provides a 3-column view showing the (1) date, (2) user and (3) tag:

[image]

The [Research Assistant badge page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/173/research-assistant) provides a similar 3-column view without any possibility of showing content in the "badge column" - it wouldn't make sense to list 50 tags here...

For consistency with other badges where a 2-column approach is sufficient, can this be changed?

Here's a 2-column view as visible from the [Proofreader badge page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/155/proofreader):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This would definitely make more sense, *and* it would actually be really easy to change for SE:

- The three-column view has each user with a class `single-badge-row-reason`,
- The two-column view has each user with a class `single-badge-row-double`

So, simply changing the `-reason` to `-double` changes everything!

Changing one user as an example:

> [image]

---

Note: I'm probably overly-simplifying this, but my point is that it wouldn't require extreme amounts of effort! :)